# iOS share button crashing when run on ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am working on a xcode project in objective-c and i want a share button on my ios application to share things i watched a tutorial on youtube here's the link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkrOKN_OA_A 
but when i run this code on iphone it works properly and when i run this code on ipad the xcode give's me this error :

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}}
```

I used this code :

```
- (IBAction)Share1:(id)sender {

UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"invoice_logo.png"];
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareImage];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: The application crashes

Comment: You should get an error message in the console. Which is it? At least, there is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, SIGABRT, etc.

Comment: int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}}

Comment: You are not giving us the error. Learn how to debug/use XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing :

```
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes=@[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]// add your share types
```

look at the video you provided from 7:30 min

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"invoice_logo.png"];
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareImage];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                    initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = 
           CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height-50, 1.0, 1.0);

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```